# How to address every line of a mysql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

To create a dynamic table within php, I set the variable `$count` from a query, which counts the rows in specific table. Then I would like to create a table with the exact number of rows as a html table:

```
for($i=1;$i=<$count;$i++){
    echo"<tr><td>$name</td><td>$rights</td></tr>";
}
```

That's the way i want the table to be displayed. But everytime the for-loop is called, the values of `$name` and `$rights` should be taken from the database-table. But how should i handle this? I thought about a simple query selecting the name from the line where ID equals i. But then i remembered that always when i delete an entry from the table there will be gaps.
For example when there 3 entries and i delete the second one. There just are 2 entries; so the name of the second row, which ID is 3, will never be selected. Is there any way of handling this problem in an appropriated way?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing how you're executing your query. But I imagine it's something along the lines of `$name = $row['name']; $rights = $row['rights'];`

Comment: Select all of them and iterate over the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldnt use a `for` you would use a `while` or a `foreach` with the results from the query.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT id, rights FROM the_table');
?>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Rights</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if($stmt !== false): ?>
<?php foreach( $stmt as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rights'] ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```